# How do I uninstall only SSMS and Profiler for 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, profiler

I'm running SQL Server 2008R2 locally on my dev workstation, and I use SSMS and Profiler quite often.  I recently installed the July 2016 version of those tools, and I'd like to remove the 2008R2 versions in order to free-up some disk space.

What is the proper way to remove ONLY those management tools?  (I do not want to remove/break my core 2008R2 install)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Programs and Features, select SQL Server 2008 R2, and then the Remove option (people tend to panic that this will just remove everything without further input, but this merely launches a wizard):

[image]

After this, you will be guided through a wizard much like installation. On the Select Instance screen, select the "remove shared features only" option:

[image]

Then you will get to this screen, where you can select just the management tools:

[image]

Though, I don't know why you don't just leave them there. They don't take up an inordinate amount of space, and you never know when you may have to use them (e.g. to manage an SSIS package or maintenance plan from your 2008 R2 instance).

*(Also, the astute observer will note that these screen shots all came from different operating systems - I swiped them from the Internet.)*

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  The <<shared components>> choice is critical before this screen.  You mentioned it too, but I just wanted to make sure future readers see this.